# Loading Windows screenshot into SFML Image

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, sfml

In C++ code, I need to take a screenshot of a given window, store the pixels in memory, and then load them into an SFML Image object. So far, I have a handle to the window I need to screenshot and can create an HBITMAP object of it:

```
HWND window = FindWindow(TEXT("WindowName"), NULL);
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(window , &rc);
HBITMAP hbmp;
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen,
rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

PrintWindow(window, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);
GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(BITMAP), bitmap);
```

Now to be honest, I'm not really much of a Windows guy and I don't understand what's really happening with this WinAPI stuff here, this is just some code I found online to get screenshots. What I need to do is get this into some type of standard format that I can pass into SFML's function:

```
sf::Image::loadFromMemory(const void *  data, std::size_t size)
```

And preferably something that will also be easy to send over a socket connection later. How can I get a nice, non-Windows-specific format for my screenshot?

Comment: I suppose [Device-Independent Bitmaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183562.aspx) are too Windows-specific for your taste. Looks like your endeavor will have to come to an end. Apart from that, `PrintWindow` will not - in general - produce a screenshot. Windows are not required to handle `WM_PRINT` messages, and most custom implementations won't. Even if you'd go with `BitBlt` instead, an application could simply call [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx) and you're left with a classy, black rectangle.

Comment: Why aren't you just using SFML's `window.capture()` function?

Comment: @Lukas, I can't use the capture() function because it only captures the "current window", and I need to be able to specify a window that might not be the active one. IInspectable, regardless of whether the bitmap is device-independent, all the functions used to get it are windows-specific and therefore I am not overly familiar with them. Like I mentioned in the OP, I can already get an HBITMAP object that I can display, I'm just looking for a cleaner method of doing it and putting it into a format that doesn't use WinAPI functions.

Comment: [GetDIBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879.aspx) - turning your `HBITMAP`s into raw pixel buffers since 1995.